# Problem with "<" and ">" parsing JSON data in Node.js

Tags: node.js, json, express, parsing, tags

I have a function in server side like this,

```
const fs = require("fs");

const file = __dirname + "/public/json-data/productData.json"; 

fs.readFile(file, function(err, data) {
   exports.getProductDataList = function() {
     if(err)
       console.log(err);
     else {
       let comments = JSON.parse(data);
    
       return comments;
     }
   }
});
```

However, when the comments is returned, despite I write

```
"0" : "<p>asdsa</p>",
```

in JSON file, there is a problem. I managed to transfer the content of the json file into the server.js. The list inside the JSON file is stored in an object called productDataList. However when I put the first value of the object into a div like this:

```
<div><%= productDataList[0] %><div>
```

It does not add the paragraph tag as shown but instead, it shows `<p>asdsa</p>` as a complete text. Is there any suggestion?

Solution 1:
I tried adding it like this to JSON file:

```
"0" : "&lt;p&gt;  <p>asdsa</p>  &lt;/p&gt;",
```

For some reason, it exactly shows what it is written in browser.

[image]

Comment: @rici: He wants it to be a HTML tag.

Comment: @Take-Some-Bytes: ah, you're right. So it is being escaped somewhere.

Comment: @ginger: how do you store the list into `productDataList`?

Comment: I store it in JSON file. It is given up top, how it is pulled up and injected into the HTML

Comment: If you're using [this template system](https://ejs.co/), then you should use `<%-` instead of `<%=` when you want to include HTML tags as-is.